# Display a button when the shiny app launches for first time that will lead to tabItems content

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the `shiny` app below which includes tabItems. I would like when the app is launched for first time to display an `actionbutton` which will be out of the tabItems content. Then when I press it I will be moved into the `Consent` tabItem. This button will have no use from there and later and it should be disappeared since the tabItems' content will be displayed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

mytitle <- paste0("")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1250px ;font-size: 44px ;color:#001641;font-family:Chronicle Display Light; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),
    
    
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent", 
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6")),
    
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
  
    '))),
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      
      actionButton("button", "Get started",style='padding:4px; font-size:140%'),
      tabItems(
        tabItem("conse",
textInput("pos", label = ("Position"), value = "")

                )
        

      )
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
    
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                       selected = "conse")
      
      
    })
    
  }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

mytitle <- paste0("")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1250px ;font-size: 44px ;color:#001641;font-family:Chronicle Display Light; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),


    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent",
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6") ),

  ),  class = "dropdown")
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('

    '))),
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),

      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),

      actionButton("button", "Get started",style='padding:4px; font-size:140%'),
      tabItems(
        tabItem("conse", textInput("pos", label = ("Position"), value = "") )
      )

    )

  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    shinyjs::hide("conse")
    shinyjs::hide("pos")

    observeEvent(input$button, {
      shinyjs::show("conse")
      shinyjs::show("pos")
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                     selected = "conse")
      shinyjs::hide("button")

    })

  }
  )
)
```

Comment: Im sorry maybe I was not clear. When the app is launched only the 'Get Started' button should be displayed in the main body. When I push it I will be moved into the 'Consent' tab and therefore it canot be seen any more.

Comment: You mean "Get Start" button should disappear after you click it once?

Comment: Yes like this.thanks, I wonder if the tab Consent can be visible and therefore pushable even before pressing the Get Started.

Comment: Sure.  Please comment out the line `shinyjs::hide("conse")`

Comment: I created a new Q to be fair https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535690/activate-tabitem-with-either-an-actionbutton-or-another-actionbutton-in-ashiny-a