# Activate tabItem with either an actionButton or another actionButton in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below which includes tabItems. I would like when the app is launched for first time to display an actionbutton which will be out of the tabItems content. Then when I press it I will be moved into the Consent tabItem. This button will have no use from there and later and it should be disappeared since the tabItems' content will be displayed. I want also the user to be able to press `Consent` button before pressing `"Get Started"` button and still be able to move to `Consent` tabItem.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

mytitle <- paste0("")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1250px ;font-size: 44px ;color:#001641;font-family:Chronicle Display Light; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),


    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent",
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6") ),

  ),  class = "dropdown")
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('

    '))),
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),

      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),

      actionButton("button", "Get started",style='padding:4px; font-size:140%'),
      tabItems(
        tabItem("conse", textInput("pos", label = ("Position"), value = "") )
      )

    )

  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    shinyjs::hide("conse")
    shinyjs::hide("pos")

    observeEvent(input$button, {
      shinyjs::show("conse")
      shinyjs::show("pos")
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                     selected = "conse")
      shinyjs::hide("button")

    })

  }
  )
)
```

Comment: Please note that your question requires more clarity.  For example, if you press consent (without pressing Get Started), you go to that tab.  Then the button "Get Started" should still be displayed or not? Assuming it is not, how do you go back to "Get Started" as it was not part of any tab?  If no need to display "Get Started" button after clicking either consent or Get Started button, it should be fine to define one observeEvent for either button.

Comment: if you go straight to the tab by clicking on 'Content' you cannot return to Get started and display that again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is use `shinyjs` to hide the element in the tabItem.  Relevant code is below.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )
                               ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),

      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),

      actionButton("button", "Get started", style='padding:4px; font-size:140%'),
      tabItems(
        tabItem("conse", textInput("pos", label = ("Position"), value = "")
                )
      )

    )
  ),

  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    shinyjs::hide("pos")

    observeEvent(input$button, {
      shinyjs::show("pos")
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "conse")
      shinyjs::hide("button")

    })
    observeEvent(input$conse, {
        shinyjs::show("pos")
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "conse")
        shinyjs::hide("button")

    })

  }
  )
)
```

Another way to do it is use `conditionalPanel` to hide all items in the tab.  Depending on your use case, this may be a better option.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      
      actionButton("button", "Get started", style='padding:4px; font-size:140%'),
      
      tabItems(
        tabItem("conse", 
                conditionalPanel(condition = "input.conse >0 || input.button>0",
                                 textInput("pos", label = ("Position"), value = "")
                )
        )
      )
      
    )
  ),
  
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "conse")
      shinyjs::hide("button")
      
    })
    observeEvent(input$conse, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "conse")
      shinyjs::hide("button")
    })
    
  }
  )
)
```

Comment: both certainly work i ll see what fits me best

Comment: hey based on your code I am trying this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567297/activate-the-same-event-with-the-use-of-two-different-actionbuttons-in-a-shiny-a