# Activate the same event with the use of two different actionbuttons in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below. When the app is launched for 1st time it displays an actionbutton `Get Started` in the main body and 3 actionbuttons in the header.

1. The user can press whichever of these 3 header buttons he wishes before
   pressing the `Get Started` button. Its ok that he cannot see the `Get Started` button again

If he press `Consent` he will be moved in the `Consent` tabItem. Then he can write a name press `Run Project` and see the plot in the `Results` tabItem.

If he press `Run Project` before having typed a name in `Consent` he will be moved in `Consent` automatically in order to type a name.

If he press `Results` before having typed a name in `Consent` he will be moved in Consent automatically in order to type a name.

2. The user press the `Get Started` button first and he moves to the
   `Consent` tab in order to type a name and then `Run Project` to move to
   Results.

I think that my code deos not work because of the conflict of the two actionbuttons `Run Project` and `Get Started`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
mytitle <- paste0("")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1250px ;font-size: 44px ;color:#001641;font-family:Chronicle Display Light; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),
    
    
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent",
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6") ),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("rp", "Run Project",
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6") ),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("res", "Results",
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6") ),
    
  ),  class = "dropdown")
)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart")),
                                           menuItem("Results", tabName = "res", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      
      actionButton("button", "Get started", style='padding:4px; font-size:140%'),
      
      tabItems(
        tabItem("conse", 
                conditionalPanel(condition = "input.conse >0 || input.button>0",
                                 textInput("nam", label = ("Name"), value = "")
                                 
                                 
                )
        ),
        tabItem("res", uiOutput('markdown')
                                 
        )
        
      )
      
    )
  ),
  
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "conse")
      shinyjs::hide("button")
      
    })
    observeEvent(input$conse, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "conse")
      shinyjs::hide("button")
    })
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      if (input$nam=="") {
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                       selected = "conse")
      }
      else{
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "res")
      }
      
    })
    observeEvent(input$rp, {
      if (input$nam=="") {
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                       selected = "conse")
      }
      else{
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "res")
        
      }
      
    })
    output$markdown <- renderUI({input$rp
      
      if (input$nam==""){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else{
        isolate(plot(iris))
          
      }
    })
  }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will suffice.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(stringi)

mytitle <- paste0("Test")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1250px ;font-size: 44px ;color:#001641;font-family:Chronicle Display Light; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),
    
    
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent",
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6") ),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("rp", "Run Project",
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6") ),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("res", "Results",
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6") ),
    
  ),  class = "dropdown")
)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart")),
                                           menuItem("Results", tabName = "res", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      
      actionButton("button", "Get started", style='padding:4px; font-size:140%'),
      
      tabItems(
        tabItem("conse", 
                #conditionalPanel(condition = "input.conse >0 || input.button>0 ",
                                 textInput("nam", label = ("Name"), value = "")
                #)
        ),
        tabItem("res", plotOutput('markdown')
                
        )
        
      )
      
    )
  ),
  
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    shinyjs::hide("nam")
    
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      shinyjs::show("nam")
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "conse")
      shinyjs::hide("button")
      
    })
    observeEvent(input$conse, {
      shinyjs::show("nam")
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "conse")
      shinyjs::hide("button")
      
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$rp, {
      shinyjs::hide("button")
      p <- stri_stats_latex(input$nam)[1]
      if (is.null(input$nam) | input$nam=="" | p<1) {
        shinyjs::show("nam")
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "conse")
      }else{
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "res")
      }
      
    })
    observeEvent(input$res, {
      shinyjs::hide("button")
      p <- stri_stats_latex(input$nam)[1]
      if (is.null(input$nam) | input$nam=="" | p<1) {
        shinyjs::show("nam")
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "conse")
      }else{
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = "res")
      }
      
    })
    
    output$markdown <- renderPlot({ # input$rp
      p <- stri_stats_latex(input$nam)[1]
      if (is.null(input$nam) | input$nam=="" | p<1){
        return(NULL)
      }else{
        isolate(plot(iris))
      }
    })
  }
  )
)
```

Comment: almost great besides the fact that the get started button should be disappeared when I click on Run Project or Results buttons just like it happens when I click on Consent